# How to increase spacing between paragraphs in Crystal Reports PDF

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports, spacing, paragraph

I have a report that I'm exporting to PDF using the VS2008 version of Crystal Reports. There is a field that displays a product description that contains HTML data pulled from my database so I've set Text Interpretation to HTML for the field.  The text displays fine with all the appropriate HTML formatting, however, there is only a single line-space between paragraphs.  I've tried adding multiple <p> and multiple <br> tags to increase the spacing but this does not work.  How can I increase the spacing between paragraphs in an HTML field that I'm exporting to PDF?

Comment: Is the spacing correct in the report viewer? Is it the pdf conversion that messes it up?

Comment: The spacing is incorrect in the report viewer as well, the paragraphs are only separated by a single space. If I use a cssclass to try and add spacing, will it be included in the PDF when I export it?  I haven't had much success with styling with CSS, I was just wondering.

Comment: the html interpretation is very basic...only tags like p, br, b, i, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a little messing around, try using this for a line break `&nbsp;<br>`

Comment: That did it dotjoe.  You're a life saver. I was pretty close because I'd tried &lt;p&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/p&gt; . Thanks again.

Comment: cool. I figured you could trick it, sense the <br> works when text is involved. It just doesn't like whitespace or something.

Comment: Just wanted to add that &nbsp;<br> works as well.  The <br>&nbsp; was indenting the paragraph by one space.

Comment: 3 years later... Trying to ghetto "Vertically Align" and a simple `"<br>" + ` doesn't work. `&nbsp;"<br>" + ` does. You would think Vertically Center would be an option without having to resort to this "Hack".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. the following step fix the issue

In my case the field is in "Details" Section of a SubReport. Crystal Report version is X1 R2.

Step 1. Select the SubReport, right click and select "Edit SubReport" option
Step 2. Select the Section Expert of the Details Section in the SubReport.
Step 3. Select the Layout tab
Step 4. Change the Vertical (Gap Between Details) as 0.109 cm
Step 5. Select Printing Direction as "Down then Across"
Step 6. Select option "Format Groups with multiple column
Step 7. Press Ok and save the SubReport / Main Report

By doing this i can see the space between the paragraphs for the field which has interpretation as "HTML TEXT"